# Angular 11 - I can't display a value from local storage

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I want the value from my local storage to be displayed in my input field. here is my attempt and it's not working.

ts

```
 this.additionalID = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('some-key'));
  this.formValueWebinar.controls['user_id'].setValue(this.additionalID);
```

html

```
 <mat-form-field class="webinarTitleInput " appearance="outline">
               <mat-label class="font">Enter User ID</mat-label>
               <input type="text" matInput placeholder="User ID" formControlName='user_id' [innerHtml]= 'this.additionalID'>
            </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug `this.additionalID` ? It might be `null` or `undefined`

Comment: I checked it and it has a value

Comment: Could you confirm whether the `setValue` is being executed before or after the form has been initialized? Can you try running `this.formValueWebinar.controls['user_id'].setValue(this.additionalID)` within the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook of the app?

Comment: Can you share more data like the structure of `this.formValueWebinar` and how you binded `this.formValueWebinar` in template

Answer (score 0):

Try with the patch value

```
this.formValueWebinar.controls['user_id'].patchValue(this.additionalID);
```

Some times the setValues function does not updated the value it just set it on code and does not update try with patch

Comment: It's still not showing